# Text exceeding grid in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

As you can see, "11111111..." and "22222222..." are overlapping. I think this is because the former exceeds the grid it belongs to, i.e. `<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Test
  </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
        <h2>11111111111111111111111111111111</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
        <h2>22222222222222222222222222222222</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

It looks like this in my browser(Safari Version 9.1.2 (11601.7.7)):

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide a jsFiddle please. Because in snippet nothing seems wrong here.

Comment: You're missing the `<div class="row">...</div>` between the container and the columns.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik Seems that a jsFiddle cannot reproduce my problem. I've added a screenshot. Hope that'll be helpful.

Comment: @KhalidT. Question updated: After adding that, the same problem remains...

Comment: @sunqingyao: By the way, you're not doing anything wrong. If you're expecting to have such LONG one-word strings on your page, you might want to set the `overflow-x` property to `hidden` or `auto` (depending on what you want to display)

Comment: @KhalidT. I'm not expecting one-word strings are. Instead, I want them to "fold" automatically, just like grids on [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `word-wrap: break-word;` to h2 element. because the default setting for word-wrap is normal. which wrap only for limited set of split tokens (example: whitespaces, hyphens).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
      <h2 class="w-wrap">11111111111111111111111111111111</h2>
      <p class="text-muted ">11111111111111111111111111111111</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4">
      <h2 class="w-wrap">22222222222222222222222222222222</h2>
      <p class="text-muted">22222222222222222222222222222222</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.w-wrap{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! And do you know why texts on [this example page](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/) aren't overlapping? I couldn't find anything like `word-wrap: break-word;` when inspecting element.

Comment: It will overlap if there will be no whitespace or hypen present between the words.(eg: try...  Headinggggggggggggggggggggggggggg). `word-wrap: break-word;` style need to be add to fix the issue its not included in bootstrap.